# Updating the DOM after local state change via useEffect Hook

Tags: reactjs

The component is rendered for the first time with default component. After the parent component fetches optional data from API, I need to update the DOM. Currently, component is successfully rerendered on setting local state within useEffect. I need to call a function that changes the property of the span element based on that new state.

```
useEffect(() => {
        setCurrentRating(props.rating);
        console.log('Runned only first time', currentRating);
        // needed to call setRating function that changes the color of star elements
    }, [props.rating]);

    const setRating = (ev) => {
        console.log('Setting initial retting', currentRating);
        const starElements = ratingEl.current.getElementsByClassName('star');
        Array.from(starElements).forEach(starEl => {
          starEl.style.color =
            currentRating >= starEl.dataset.value ? 'green' : 'gray';
        });
    }
```

Comment: React DON'T WANT you edit the DOM, is the job of React and not you. You must have a component that interact with props,

Comment: It is anti-pattern to manipulate the DOM directly in React. Describe in state/props/JSX what you want rendered to the DOM and React handles it.